# Can we change the url in ajax script when ajax is using in MVC?

Tags: ajax

Can we change the url in ajax script when ajax is using in MVC? & How it can be done?

Comment: to answer properly it will better if u mention which language you are using like PHP, Ruby-on-Rails etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean you change the page (or url) instead of some div Using Ajax?

if this is Question Answer is **YES**

EDITED:

It can be done in Rails using:-

```
  render :update do |page|
    page.redirect_to "www.google.co.in"
  end
```

Comment: will you please post a code how you change the div using asp.net as you don't tag initially i answer it.Please paste your code so that i can help you.To know how it done in rails check my EDITED answer.

Comment: No i am asking if you know the code of How to change the div using Ajax then please paste it.